# SO_RCVTIMEO option on LwIP

Tags: c, sockets, udp, freertos, lwip

I'm using LwIP with FreeRTOS. My project is based on the example on this URL [FreeRTOS with LwIP project](http://www.freertos.org/FreeRTOS-Plus/FreeRTOS_Plus_IO/Demo_Applications/LPCXpresso_LPC1769/NXP_LPC1769_Demo_Description.shtml). I'm also using LPC1769 with LPCXpresso version 6. CMSIS version 2.

I'm using LwIP to stream MP3 files with a UDP socket. The transfer has a nice speed but the thing is that sometimes lwip_recvfrom blocks after thousands of operations.
I can never see the timeout condition. I think I'm doing something wrong.

The followed steps are:

```
int socket = lwip_socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);

if(lwip_setsockopt( socket,
                    SOL_SOCKET,
                    SO_RCVTIMEO,
                    (int)timeoutTimeInMiliSeconds,
                    sizeof(int)) == -1)
{
    return -1;
}
....
if(lwip_bind(protocolConfig.socket,
             (struct sockaddr *)&sLocalAddr,
             sizeof(sLocalAddr)) == -1)
{
    return -1;
}
bytesWritten = lwip_sendto( socket,
                            transmitBuffer,
                            transmitBufferIndex,
                            0,
                            (struct sockaddr *)&sDestAddr,
                            sizeof(sDestAddr));
.....
bytesReceived = lwip_recvfrom(  socket,
                                receptionBuffer,
                                receptionBufferSize,
                                0,
                                NULL,
                                NULL);

if(bytesReceived < 0)
{
   //Error stuff, this condition is never reached.
}
```

Somebody knows what's wrong here?

Answer (score 2):

Problem solved.

lwip_setsockopt has this prototype:

```
int lwip_setsockopt(int socket, int level, int option_name,const void *option_value, socklen_t option_len);
```

And I was sending by copy the value of option_value.

The timeout is working fine.

Comment: BTW, `option_value` should point to a `struct timeval *` not a `int`, unless you've defined `LWIP_SO_SNDRCVTIMEO_NONSTANDARD`